# Checking the length of strings in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let say I have the following contenteditable:

```
<div class="example" contenteditable="true" id="test">
 <div><span class="inside" >Type here</span>" "</div>
</div>
```

There is a span element inside of div. You will also notice that there is white space between `</span>` and `</div>`

This space can have either just simple white space or words. How would I check the length of string or characters in here?

For example, `</span>please</div>` should give length of 6 (from the word "please").

In other words, I am strictly looking for the length in between `</span>` and `</div>`

Any approaches?

Comment: document.querySelector('.inside').innerHTML.length. length gives the length of bytes and not letters.

Comment: try `$('.example span').text().length`

Comment: You want length of <span class="inside" >Type here</span> or  </span>please</div> ?

Comment: The latter. so the length from the </span> and </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `nextSibling` of `span` node, then use its `nodeValue` property to get text.

```js
var node = document.querySelector('.inside').nextSibling;
console.log(node.nodeValue.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example" contenteditable="true" id="test">
  <div><span class="inside">Type here</span>please</div>
</div>
```

Using partial jQuery, here `get(index)` is used to fetch the underlying DOM element

```js
var contenteditable = $('[contenteditable] div span').get(0).nextSibling;
console.log(contenteditable.nodeValue.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example" contenteditable="true" id="test">
  <div><span class="inside">Type here</span>please</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `nextSibling` property. The `nextSibling` property returns the node immediately following the specified node, in the same tree level.

Please try this:

```
var length = document.getElementsByClassName("inside")[0].nextSibling.length
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("inside")[0].nextSibling.length);
```

```html
<div class="example" contenteditable="true" id="test">
 <div><span class="inside" >Type here</span>please</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The text on the right of span is as well text node so you can check its length by element.childNodes[index] or element.lastChild

```js
var cont = document.getElementById('test');

console.log(cont.children[0].lastChild.length);
```

```html
<div class="example" contenteditable="true" id="test">
 <div><span class="inside" >Type here </span>please</div>
</div>
```